# Cannot find 'ArchiveByteStream' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, compression, ios14

I've been trying to understand AppleArchive Framework's uses and according to Apple's documented example, I've tried a Compression sample but I'm getting errors that 'ArchiveByteStream' and 'FilePermissions' cannot be found. Any help and tips would be nice, thanks.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_single_files?language=objc

guard let readFileStream = ArchiveByteStream.fileStream(
path: file,
mode: .readOnly,
options: [ ],
permissions: FilePermissions(rawValue: 0o644)) else {
return
}

Comment: Did you import AppleArchive?

Comment: Yes... I have imported it and getting the error ...

Comment: I don't know who put a -1 on this, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: got same issue xcode 12.1 swift 5+

Comment: Please check https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665465 It's a bug by Apple. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @JohnKenneth  Did you find any lead into this issue???

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an [Apple issue when targeting Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665465).

You can wrap this code with and `if targetEnviornment` clause:

```swift
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
guard let readFileStream = ArchiveByteStream.fileStream( path: file, mode: .readOnly, options: [ ], permissions: FilePermissions(rawValue: 0o644)) else { return }
#else
fatalError("Apple Archive isn't supported on simulator https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665465")
#endif
```